# Set of handlers for commonly used functionalities

Tags: javascript

I am developing [a set of simple JS functions](https://github.com/kshitiz12345/littlejs-javascript) which can be used for most commonly required JS functionalities. I want the functions to be very easy to use for new JS developers.

Is the code structured well?  How can it be improved?

```
"use strict";
/* getElement, elementBase must be included */
var littleJS = function() {

   var elementNotFound = function() { console.log('No element found'); }

    var little = {
    // Override this function to execute statements when an ajax call is made   
    'startAjaxFunc' : null,

    // Override this function to execute statements when an ajax call gets over
    'stopAjaxFunc' : null,

    /* To make ajax call. First parameter is JSON of async (true or false), method (default GET), returnType (default JSON), data to be sent and url to be hit. 
       Second parameter is callback function that will be called on success */
    'makeAjaxCall' : function(args, callback) {
            if (!args.async)
                args.async = true;
            if (!args.method)
                args.method = "GET";
            if (!args.returnType)
                args.returnType = "JSON";
            if (!args.data)
                args.data = {};
            var JSONToURLString = function(obj) {
                var urlPara = '';
                for ( var key in obj) {
                    urlPara = urlPara + key + '=' + obj[key] + '&';
                }
                return urlPara.substring(0, urlPara.length - 1);
            };

            args.data = JSONToURLString(args.data);
            if (args.method === "GET")
                args.url = args.url + '?' + args.data;

            var xmlhttp;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome,
                // Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {// code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    switch (args.returnType) {
                    case 'json':
                    case 'JSON':
                        callback(JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText));
                        break;
                    case 'text':
                        callback(xmlhttp.responseText);
                    }
                    if (little.stopAjaxFunc)
                        little.stopAjaxFunc();
                }
            };
            if (little.startAjaxFunc)
                little.startAjaxFunc();
            xmlhttp.open(args.method, args.url, args.async);
            xmlhttp.send(args.data);
    },


    'elementBase' : function() {
        var processElement = function(element, callback) {
            if (typeof (element.length) !== 'undefined') {
                var length = element.length;
                for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    var singleElement = element[i];
                    callback(singleElement);
                }
            } else {
                callback(element);
            }
        };
        return {
            'processElement' : processElement
        };
    },


    /* To show or hide element. Call displayElement.hideElement to hide and displayElement.showElement to show element. 
       Default display class is block to show element but one can pass display class name as third parameter in displayElement.showElement */ 
    'displayElement' : {

        'previousDisplayStatus' : {},

        'defaultDisplayClass' : 'block',

        'hideElement' : function(type, reference) {
            var cssValue = little.getCSSPropertyValue(type,
                    reference, 'display');
            var currentDisplayStatus;
            if(cssValue) currentDisplayStatus = cssValue[0];
            if (currentDisplayStatus && currentDisplayStatus !== 'none') 
                this.previousDisplayStatus[type + reference] = currentDisplayStatus;
            var display = 'none';
            var element = little.getElement(type, reference);
            little.elementBase().processElement(element,
                    function(element) {
                        element.style.display = display;
                    });
        },

        'showElement' : function(type, reference, userDefinedDisplayClass) {
            if (!this.previousDisplayStatus[type + reference]
                    && !userDefinedDisplayClass)
                var display = this.defaultDisplayClass;
            else
                var display = userDefinedDisplayClass
                        || this.previousDisplayStatus[type + reference];

            var element = little.getElement(type, reference);
            if(element)
                little.elementBase().processElement(element,
                        function(element) {
                            element.style.display = display;
                        });
        }

    },


    /*  Adding / removing events to / from elements. 
        Effects like click, mouseover can be passed as an array and action is any function to be called after effect.*/
    'addEventToElement' : function (type, reference, effect, action) {
        var element = little.getElement(type, reference);
        if(element)
            if(typeof(effect) === 'string') {
                little.elementBase().processElement(element, function(element) {
                    element.addEventListener(effect, action);
                });
            } else {
                var length = effect.length;
                for(var i=0;i < length; i++) {
                    little.elementBase().processElement(element, function(element) {
                        element.addEventListener(effect[i], action);
                    });
                }
            }
        else 
            elementNotFound();  
    },


    // get selected checkboxes text and respective values as JSON contained in an element like div or span. Return  type is array
    'getCheckboxSelectedValues' : function (reference) {
        var fieldList = document.querySelectorAll(reference);
        if(fieldList) {
                var checkedIdValues = [];
                var length = fieldList.length;
                for ( var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
                    var currentField = fieldList[i];
                    if (currentField.checked){
                        checkedIdValues.push(currentField.value);
                    }
                }
                return checkedIdValues;
            }
        else 
            elementNotFound();
        },
     }

     return little; 
  };

  var little = littleJS();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy-paste your code into http://jshint.com/, it will point out many things you should fix. Try to fix them all.

---

When creating objects, you don't need to quote keys that are simple words.
For example, instead of this:

> ```
> var little = {
>     'startAjaxFunc' : null,
>     'stopAjaxFunc' : null,
> ```

This writing style is simpler and more common:

```
var little = {
    startAjaxFunc: null,
    stopAjaxFunc: null,
```

---

When iterating over an object, you need to add an `if` statement to filter unwanted properties from the prototype.
For example, instead of this:

> ```
> for ( var key in obj) {
>     urlPara = urlPara + key + '=' + obj[key] + '&';
> }
> ```

Write like this:

```
for (var key in obj) {
    if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        continue;
    }
    urlPara = urlPara + key + '=' + obj[key] + '&';
}
```

---

> ```
> if (!args.async)
>     args.async = true;
> if (!args.method)
>     args.method = "GET";
> if (!args.returnType)
>     args.returnType = "JSON";
> if (!args.data)
>     args.data = {};
> ```

There are two problems with this:

- It modifies `args`, which was passed as a parameter. It's a bad practice to modify parameters, unless they are intended to be *out parameters* in your API
- It's tedious

I propose this approach instead:

```
var initial = {
    async: true,
    method: "GET",
    returnType: "JSON",
    data: {}
};

var options = $.extend(initial, args);
```

Without jQuery, you could use a simple implementation of `extend` instead:

```
function extend(base, params) {
    for (var key in params) {
        if (params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            base[key] = params[key];
        }
    }
    return base;
}
```

Note: the fact that I modify `base` may seem to contradict with my point earlier about not modifying parameter variables. In this case this is ok, because modifying `base` is a conscious move, it's the main purpose of the method.

Comment: Thank you for your awsum reviews...I will look on those....just one thing ...I am not suppose to use jquery....is there any approach for $.extend?

Comment: You're very welcome. I added a simplified implementation of `extend`, I don't think there is an easier, built-in way.